# Sonar + JaCoco not counting Groovy code as covered

Tags: groovy, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a Groovy class with a single static method:

```
class ResponseUtil {
    static String FormatBigDecimalForUI (BigDecimal value){
        (value == null || value <= 0) ? '' : roundHalfEven(value)
    }
}
```

It has a test case or few:

```
@Test
void shouldFormatValidValue () {
    assert '1.8' == ResponseUtil.FormatBigDecimalForUI(new BigDecimal(1.7992311))
    assert '0.9' == ResponseUtil.FormatBigDecimalForUI(new BigDecimal(0.872342))
}

@Test
void shouldFormatMissingValue () {
    assert '' == ResponseUtil.FormatBigDecimalForUI(null)
}

@Test
void shouldFormatInvalidValue () {
    assert '' == ResponseUtil.FormatBigDecimalForUI(new BigDecimal(0))
    assert '' == ResponseUtil.FormatBigDecimalForUI(new BigDecimal(0.0))
    assert '' == ResponseUtil.FormatBigDecimalForUI(new BigDecimal(-1.0))
}
```

This results in `6/12` branches covered according to Sonar/JaCoCo:

[image: Half Code Coverage]

So I've changed the code to be more...verbose.  I don't think the original code is "too clever" or anything like that, but I made it more explicit and clearer.  So, here it is:

```
static String FormatBigDecimalForUI (BigDecimal value) {
    if (value == null) {
        ''
    } else if (value <= 0) {
        ''
    } else {
        roundHalfEven(value)
    }
}
```

And now, without having changed anything else, Sonar/JaCoCo report it to be fully covered:

[image: JaCoCo 100% Coverage]

Why is this the case?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a bug in Sonar/JaCoCo, as both those methods produce very similar bytecode as far as I can see...

Comment: I've run the same "how does the code coverage look" under Cobertura, and it produces the exact same results.  Half-tested on the single-line and fully-tested on the expanded version.  That's...concerning.

Comment: I've posted the two generated bytecodes [here](https://gist.github.com/e61f5f41175c6a8e076b), they both look fine to me (but obviously the multi-line code calls `areturn` more than the single line version)...  There are probably people who have hit this issue (and found workarounds) on the Groovy User mailing list...  I'd try firing an email off and see if anyone has seen this before?

Comment: Sorry for digging up an old question but I'm wondering how you are using Groovy, Jacoco, and Sonar together. This is the only reference I have seen to this combination working together.

Comment: I think we never really ended up using JaCoCo.  We are using Sonar with Groovy and Cobertura, however.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it applies to your concrete example, but keep in mind that code coverage tools typically don't work well for alternative JVM languages unless they support them explicitly. This is because virtually all of those languages generate extra byte code that may only get executed in certain cases. For example, Groovy might generate byte code for a slow path and a fast path, and might decide between them automatically, without the user having a say.

The situation might improve with Groovy 3.0, which will be designed around Java invokedynamic, meaning that less "magic" byte code will have to be generated. Meanwhile, I've heard that Clover has explicit Groovy support, although I don't know how up-to-date it is.

Answer (score 1):

So, as it turns out, the Jacoco plugin for Sonar explicitly looks for Java code. I know this, as I debugged through it. It decodes the jacoco exec file and assumes any file is a JavaFile, which it doesn't find, and then says you have no coverage information.

Because of this, I grabbed the source code to the Jacoco plugin (it vanished from their Subversion repository, and never appeared on Github that I could find) and folded it into a new Groovy plugin. My updated one uses Codenarc 0.18.1 (which increases the Narc's from 32 to 305) and recognizes any kind of Jacoco file - the code in the existing plugin is unnecessarily wrong.

The source is here: https://github.com/rvowles/sonar-groovy - just build it and put it in your extensions/plugins directory.